# How I can create a button that change the array position in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, vue.js

I want a button that when pressed, changes the array position. I thought of the possibility to create an auxiliary variable to sum and the array changes position.
The problem is: When I program this, nothing changes in HTML and console of browser, JS says: "undefined". How do I fix this? I tried `var`, `let` in a function and replaces the old attribute for changing the position of the array, and didn't work.
I did not place a restriction if the counter exceeds the size of the array, but even in the first positions (1, 2 and 3), it appears `undefined`.

HTML

```
<div id="app">
     <button @click="changePos()">Generic Button</button>
</div>
```

JS

```
new Vue({
     el: '#app',
     data: {
          counter: 0,
          test: [5, 6, 7]
     },
     methods: {
          changePos(){
               this.counter++
               console.log(this.test[this.counter]) // Here appears "undefined"
          }
     }
});
```

Comment: Your snipped should work, but I would write `this.counter++` behind `console.log` to make sure that you get the first element. And it will say undefined, when your counter is higher than the length of the array minus 1.

Comment: Wow.
I thought that as you said, there would be no way to access the first position of the array. It worked, thanks! :)